# How to passed value from looping result to new object?

Tags: php, loops, html-table, odbc

How to passed value from looping result to new object using button ? 
For example :

I have input text to get order number. The result for Order number 0001 is like this

```
| Order No  | Delivery No | Invoice No | Delivery Date | Action |
=================================================================
| 0001      | D0001       | I0001      | 21-03-2018    |(process button)|
| 0001      | D0002       | I0002      | 21-03-2018    |(process button)|
```

I have no trouble to  display table above, the problem is how to make those process button work ? Process button is to display detail of one invoice. From example above, if i click process button for Invoice I0002 result will be like this

```
 |  No. Item | Item Name | Price | Qty | Amount |
   ================================================
   |  0000001  |  apple    | 5     |  2  | 10     |
   and so on..
```

So far my work for first table

```
$select_order = "SELECT ORDER_NO, DELI_NO, INV_NO, DELI_DT, AMOUNT FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_NO = '$text_input_order'";
$exec_order = odbc_exec($connSQL, $select_order);
while(odbc_fetch_row($exec_order))
{
   $get_order_no = odbc_result($exec_order, "ORDER_NO");
   $get_deli_no  = odbc_result($exec_order, "DELI_NO");
   $get_inv_no  = odbc_result($exec_order, "INV_NO");
   $get_deli_dt  = odbc_result($exec_order, "DELI_DT");
   $get_amount   = odbc_result($exec_order, "AMOUNT");
  ?>
  <tr>
     <td><? echo $get_order_no;?></td>
     <td><? echo $get_deli_no  ;?></td>
     <td><? echo $get_inv_no  ;?></td>
     <td><? echo $get_deli_dt  ;?></td>
     <td><? echo $get_amount   ;?></td>
     <td><input type="submit" value="proces" name="proces"></td>
  </tr>
  <?
}
```

Now I need your help to make second table using process button.

Comment: Your query string isn't closed where it should be. The closing ```"``` is missing at the end of the ```$select_order``` assignment.

Comment: Thx, i'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
Please made the changes as per your requirements after button click.

<script>
$(function(){
$('button[name=proces]').click(function(){
    var id= $(this).attr("id");
    //some action here
    //ex:
    window.location.href="<put your site url>?id="+id;
    //or an ajax function
  });
});
</script>
<?php 
$select_order = "SELECT ORDER_NO, DELI_NO, INV_NO, DELI_DT, AMOUNT FROM 
ORDER WHERE ORDER_NO = '$text_input_order'";
$exec_order = odbc_exec($connSQL, $select_order);
while(odbc_fetch_row($exec_order))
{
    $get_order_no = odbc_result($exec_order, "ORDER_NO");
    $get_deli_no  = odbc_result($exec_order, "DELI_NO");
    $get_inv_no  = odbc_result($exec_order, "INV_NO");
    $get_deli_dt  = odbc_result($exec_order, "DELI_DT");
    $get_amount   = odbc_result($exec_order, "AMOUNT");
?>
<tr>
 <td><? echo $get_order_no;?></td>
 <td><? echo $get_deli_no  ;?></td>
 <td><? echo $get_inv_no  ;?></td>
 <td><? echo $get_deli_dt  ;?></td>
 <td><? echo $get_amount   ;?></td>
 <td><input type="button" id=".$get_inv_no." value="proces" name="proces"></td>
</tr>
<?
}
```

Comment: thx  I'll try it.. But how to display the table on same page?

Comment: It is possible but get complicated so, I suggest to you please used new page for the displayed invoice data